# Resizing an animated gif with ImageMagick results in 40mb file

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick

I'm using this code to resize an animated gif of 300kb but the resulting gif is 40mb+.

```
$image = new \Imagick($sSourceFile);

// split
$image = $image->coalesceImages(); 

// resize each frame
foreach ($image as $key => $frame) {
    $frame->thumbnailImage(904, 678);
    $frame->setImagePage(904, 678, 0, 0);
}

// find areas that has changed between images
$image = $image->deconstructImages();

// save
$image->writeImages($sTargetFile, true);
```

I've tried optimising the frames after reading this http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_opt/#frame_opt

```
$image = $image->optimizeImageLayers(); //instead of deconstructImages()
```

But that didn't help.

Is there another way optimise the frames?

#### Update

I tried to fix it without the php plugin:

```
$command = "convert " . $sSourceFile . " -coalesce";
$command .= " -resize 904x678";
$command .= " -layers OptimizeFrame " .  $sTargetFile;
system($command);
```

That worked for a small gif of 50kb but it failed on my bigger one with this message:

```
PHP Warning: system(): Unable to fork [convert /var/www/my_folder/orig.gif -coalesce  -layers OptimizeFrame /var/www/my_folder/new.gif] in /var/www/my_folder/test.php on line 100
```

#### Update - info for Glenn Randers-Pehrson's comments:

The imagemagick identity command gives me the following on my old and new gifs:

```
old.gif[0] GIF 904x678 904x678+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 321KB 0.010u 0:00.019
old.gif[1] GIF 2x3 904x678+516+430 8-bit sRGB 256c 321KB 0.040u 0:00.049
old.gif[2] GIF 4x5 904x678+515+429 8-bit sRGB 256c 321KB 0.040u 0:00.049
old.gif[3] GIF 6x7 904x678+514+428 8-bit sRGB 256c 321KB 0.040u 0:00.049
old.gif[4] GIF 8x9 904x678+513+427 8-bit sRGB 256c 321KB 0.040u 0:00.049
...
old.gif[480] GIF 236x45 904x678+288+552 8-bit sRGB 256c 321KB 0.030u 0:00.029
old.gif[481] GIF 232x45 904x678+288+552 8-bit sRGB 256c 321KB 0.030u 0:00.029
old.gif[482] GIF 1x1 904x678+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 321KB 0.030u 0:00.029
old.gif[483] GIF 1x1 904x678+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 321KB 0.030u 0:00.029
old.gif[484] GIF 1x1 904x678+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 321KB 0.030u 0:00.029

new.gif[0] GIF 904x678 904x678+0+0 8-bit sRGB 64c 48.27MB 0.030u 0:00.040
new.gif[1] GIF 904x678 904x678+0+0 8-bit sRGB 64c 48.27MB 0.060u 0:00.060
new.gif[2] GIF 904x678 904x678+0+0 8-bit sRGB 64c 48.27MB 0.060u 0:00.060
new.gif[3] GIF 904x678 904x678+0+0 8-bit sRGB 64c 48.27MB 0.060u 0:00.060
new.gif[4] GIF 904x678 904x678+0+0 8-bit sRGB 128c 48.27MB 0.060u 0:00.060
...
new.gif[480] GIF 904x678 904x678+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 48.27MB 0.030u 0:00.039
new.gif[481] GIF 904x678 904x678+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 48.27MB 0.030u 0:00.039
new.gif[482] GIF 904x678 904x678+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 48.27MB 0.030u 0:00.039
new.gif[483] GIF 904x678 904x678+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 48.27MB 0.030u 0:00.039
new.gif[484] GIF 904x678 904x678+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 48.27MB 0.030u 0:00.039
```

Using ImageMagick 6.8.7-7 Q16 x86_64 2013-11-27.

Adding --verbose to the identify gives me:

```
Image: new.gif
  Format: GIF (CompuServe graphics interchange format)
  Mime type: image/gif
  Class: PseudoClass
  Geometry: 904x678+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Type: Palette
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Red:
      min: 199 (0.780392)      max: 250 (0.980392)      mean: 236.67 (0.928118)      standard deviation: 10.9591 (0.0429769)      kurtosis: 0.887823      skewness: -1.55982    
    Green:
      min: 199 (0.780392)      max: 250 (0.980392)      mean: 236.67 (0.928118)      standard deviation: 10.9591 (0.0429769)      kurtosis: 0.887823      skewness: -1.55982    
    Blue:
      min: 199 (0.780392)      max: 249 (0.976471)      mean: 236.647 (0.928027)      standard deviation: 10.9867 (0.0430852)      kurtosis: 0.857301      skewness: -1.5512  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 199 (0.780392)      max: 250 (0.980392)      mean: 236.662 (0.928087)      standard deviation: 10.9683 (0.0430131)      kurtosis: 0.877615      skewness: -1.55695  Colors: 34
  Histogram:
         4: (199,199,199) #C7C7C7 grey78
       272: (203,203,203) #CBCBCB srgb(203,203,203)
     ... [long list removed by Tieme]
       199: (249,249,249) #F9F9F9 srgb(249,249,249)
        29: (250,250,246) #FAFAF6 srgb(250,250,246)
  Colormap entries: 64
  Colormap:
         0: (199,199,199) #C7C7C7 grey78
         1: (201,201,201) #C9C9C9 grey79
     ... [long list removed by Tieme]
        62: (  0,  0,  0) #000000 black
        63: (  0,  0,  0) #000000 black
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Background color: grey78
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: black
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 904x678+0+0
  Dispose: None
  Delay: 5x100
  Iterations: 0
  Scene: 0 of 485
  Compression: LZW
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2014-04-09T21:12:21+02:00
    date:modify: 2014-04-09T21:12:21+02:00
    signature: 6d2f4f19412c6187c28ee6ef8e71e7c59e166ab7bf151bb1ae2ab3701aff425c
  Artifacts:
    filename: new.gif
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 48.27MB
  Number pixels: 613K
  Pixels per second: 113KB
  User time: 5.370u
  Elapsed time: 0:06.430
  Version: ImageMagick 6.8.7-7 Q16 x86_64 2013-11-27 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

And for old.gif:

```
Image: old.gif
  Format: GIF (CompuServe graphics interchange format)
  Mime type: image/gif
  Class: PseudoClass
  Geometry: 904x678+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Type: PaletteAlpha
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
    alpha: 1-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Red:
      min: 199 (0.780392)      max: 251 (0.984314)      mean: 236.67 (0.928118)      standard deviation: 10.8629 (0.0425998)      kurtosis: 0.97992      skewness: -1.63289    
    Green:
      min: 199 (0.780392)      max: 251 (0.984314)      mean: 236.67 (0.928118)      standard deviation: 10.8629 (0.0425998)      kurtosis: 0.97992      skewness: -1.63289    
    Blue:
      min: 199 (0.780392)      max: 251 (0.984314)      mean: 236.647 (0.928027)      standard deviation: 10.9006 (0.0427473)      kurtosis: 0.938884      skewness: -1.62081    
    Alpha:
      min: 255 (1)      max: 255 (1)      mean: 255 (1)      standard deviation: 0 (0)      kurtosis: 0      skewness: 0  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0 (0)      max: 251 (0.984314)      mean: 177.497 (0.696066)      standard deviation: 9.41846 (0.0369351)      kurtosis: 32894      skewness: -1470.41  Colors: 50
  Histogram:
         4: (199,199,199,255) #C7C7C7 grey78
         5: (201,201,201,255) #C9C9C9 grey79
     ... [long list removed by Tieme]
         1: (250,250,246,255) #FAFAF6 srgba(250,250,246,1)
         1: (251,251,251,255) #FBFBFB srgba(251,251,251,1)
  Colormap entries: 256
  Colormap:
         0: (225,225,223,255) #E1E1DF srgba(225,225,223,1)
         1: (214, 72, 68,255) #D64844 srgba(214,72,68,1)
     ... [long list removed by Tieme]
       254: (242,242,242,255) #F2F2F2 grey95
       255: (255,255,255,  0) #FFFFFF00 srgba(255,255,255,0)
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Background color: srgba(255,255,255,0)
  Border color: srgba(223,223,223,1)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: srgba(255,255,255,0)
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 904x678+0+0
  Dispose: None
  Delay: 5x100
  Iterations: 0
  Scene: 0 of 485
  Compression: LZW
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2014-04-10T09:35:49+02:00
    date:modify: 2014-04-03T11:42:15+02:00
    signature: 5edcc0c3235de10a527f91b246054e2b15d17d16287ddc74001be7f7e9381c0a
  Artifacts:
    filename: old.gif
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 321KB
  Number pixels: 613K
  Pixels per second: 5.108MB
  User time: 0.080u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.120
  Version: ImageMagick 6.8.7-7 Q16 x86_64 2013-11-27 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Comment: Are you sure that your output is being written in GIF format?  Use the ImageMagick commandline "identify Targetfilename" to find out.

Comment: Yeah It's a gif, I've updated my answer for you.

Comment: 38 frames times 900 times 900 is only 30.8MB.  So it looks as though you have uncompressed GIFs with an extra 18MB of junk.  What does "identify -verbose new.gif" tell you?  Try "-compress zip" although if you have a really old version of ImageMagick that probably won't help.  You didn't say what version you've got.

Comment: Sorry 900x900 was 904x768, modified it a bit thinking it was clearer for SO. Updated the answer. Also added the identify info the the old gif. Looks like the new one is missing the alpha channel and is redoing all the information in all the frames isn't it?

Comment: OK, and 486 frames instead of 38, so 904*678*486=297,875,232 so you've got a compression rate of around 7:1, but, for example the second frame is the full 904x678 instead of 2x3 so the problem is as you observed, the optimization didn't work.  I think "-layers optimizeframe" was the right thing to try.  Maybe you just ran out of memory (300Mpix times 4 bytes per pixel is 1.2Gbytes for the working storage).  You did have a transparent white entry in old.gif but apparently no transparent pixels because it doesn't show up in the histogram.  Compression is "LZW" in both files which is correct.

Comment: Okay cool. I'm gonna try the "-layers optimizeframe" on a machine with more memory. Weird though that the php plugin is not able to add the optimisation. Thanks for your help

Comment: The ImageMagick documentation says "-layers optimize-frame" but the option was changed to CamelCase ("OptimizeFrame") quite a while ago.  Maybe the plugin still uses the old syntax, so give it a try ("-layers optimize-frame").

Comment: Both syntaxes seem to work fine in the terminal. I'll give it a spin with php as soon as I have some time.